# Django Heroku push failing

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm running accross an error trying to push my Django project up to Heroku and I was looking to see if anyone had any insight.

```
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

I am guessing it is because of my folder structure in the git repo but I am not sure.  My project is setup like this:

```
/subfolder/djangoproject/

/subfolder/requirements.txt
```

My Proc file content looks like this:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload --settings=djangoproject.settings.heroku
```

I have my project setting split and they work fine on my local.  (In other words I having a setting directory with an **init**.py in it.)

I tried this:

```
/Procfile
```

and this:

```
/subfolder/Procfile
```

but neither worked.

Can this folder structure be the culprit?  I was under the impression that the requirements.txt was how Heroku found where the project folder was.

Thanks

---

I wanted to add my solve for the first issue I had and then post the new issue I am having.

The solve I first did was to move the Procfile and requirements.txt files to the root level of the project.  The second thing I did was edit the Procfile in so the path to the manage.py script was to the proper location

```
web: python subfolder/djangoproject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload --settings=djangoproject.settings.heroku
```

I've hit a new error now when trying to run a syncdb.  It seems to go through the process but nothing takes.  In other words, if I run syncdb once and then run it a second time, it wants to set everything up all over again.  Any thoughts on what I may have configures wrong to make the DB not save it's data?  Should I use the setting for the DB from the dashboard or keep this line in the Django config:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried some other things and have got past this issue but hit another.

Answer (score 1):

You need requirements.txt or setup.py in the root of the repo.

See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect

Comment: I have the requirements.txt but the Heroku docs don't mention anything about having a setup.py.  Also my other projects don't have it.  What do you get with the setup.py being in your project?

Comment: You'll have to follow their logic in https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile