# Difficulties pushing application to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, github

I am unable to push my Django application to Heroku from github. I have already synced the files inside the App directory. After that I followed this procedure given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492538/error-pushing-django-project-to-heroku)

1. cloning your git repo
2. removing the virtualenv==1.8.4 from your requirements.txt
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "removing virtualenv requirement
5. git push heroku master

Everything works fine upto step 4. After execution of step 4, it says

```
#On Branch master
nothing to commit , working directory clean
```

When I execute the step 5, I encounter this error. I don't know what this means.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 5.63 KiB, done.
Total 16 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:tranquil-bastion-1294.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tranquil-bastion-1294.git'
```

Kindly guide me what to do as this is my first deployment on Heroku. Thank you.

Comment: Have You created the environment variables required by Heroku?

Comment: @leonardo Environment variables?

Comment: You should visit the documentation in heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Comment: You also need to have a "Procfile"?, do you have it?

Comment: No, but I am trying to go stepwise according to the tutorial you have given me. I am encountering some issues.

Comment: Maybe this other question here could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400101/django-heroku-push-failing

Answer (score 1):

Does your repository have a `requirements.txt` file at the top level of you repo? That's what Heroku uses to determine whether your app should use the Python build pack. Details:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect